# Sofrim selling other's K'tav rather than their own

Tags: tefilin, mezuzah, safrus

Some of the websites by sofrim which I have seen ([this](http://mezuzadepot.com) and [this](http://stam.net)) show that the sofrim who run them do not write for themselves. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

There is an inyan that one should not buy STaM from someone who is not a certified sofer.

Someone could have a talent for checking, buying, and selling STaM without being really good at writing them. Such a person could have qualified as a sofer on the strength of his knowledge of halachos while only possessing limited skill  at (or interest in) the writing aspect. This is the sort of sofer who would sell others work without selling his own.

Answer (score 2):

Its a function of economics. A sofer only makes money as long as he is writing and has a buyer for what he is writing. A broker gives them guaranteed customers and frees the sofer's time to write as opposed to dealing with customers.